# Using TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException can avoid the process being killed?

Tags: c#, multithreading, exception, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

As I know, if there's unhandled exception in task, and if you don't handle TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException, it will error later when it gets collected/finalized, and will kill your process.**(I should emphasize that it is in .net4.0. I know we can suppress the unhandled exception in .net4.5 by default.)**

This means that if I use the TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException, the application can be survived? I tested below code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += (o, ev) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ev.Exception); 
        Console.WriteLine("---------");
    };


    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            var t = Task.Factory.StartNew<int>(() =>
                             { throw new Exception("xxxxxx"); return 1; },
                CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.Default);
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("error");
        }
    }

    while (true)
    {
        GC.Collect();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

This code creates 10 tasks and each task throws an unhandled exception.
And the UnobservedTaskException is triggered once. Then the application is broken.
**(I tried to create only one task, in this case the application isn't broken.)**

So my conclusion is that using the UnobservedTaskException event is not useful, process still can be killed. Am I right??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call [`UnobservedTaskExceptionEventArgs.SetObserved`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.unobservedtaskexceptioneventargs.setobserved(v=vs.110).aspx) to make it an observed exception:

```
TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += (o, ev) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine(ev.Exception); 
    Console.WriteLine("---------");
    ev.SetObserved();
};
```

Comment: Looks like you need to call `SetObserved` on the `UnobservedTaskExceptionEventArgs` - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.unobservedtaskexceptioneventargs.setobserved(v=vs.110).aspx.

Comment: @DanielKelley You're right, didn't notice. Fixed my answer.